# In my ASP.net MVC application, a library needs a Page() parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently coding my first MVC 4 application for a company.
In it, I need to use an internal library developped by another team (I can not have the source code and they can not update the library as fast as I need).
A method in this library needs one System.Web.UI.Page parameter.

With MVC, it seems impossible (or tricky) to be able to have the equivalent object.

I tried different things to try to create an object Page like :

```
var page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
var requestField = typeof(System.Web.UI.Page).GetField("_request", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
requestField.SetValue(page, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request);
```

but unfortunately it does not make the job.

I hope I could handle this without rewrite my application in an older way :-/

Thank you all for your ideas!

Comment: its really hard to do that - what is the library doing?

Comment: I do not have access to the data this library is retrieving.
I am currently waiting for a reply from this team but it could lasts a long time (and there are not in my country).

Comment: you could look at the code with a reflector type tool

Comment: Maybe that library was not designed to be used with mvc

Comment: @dansasu11 I think so, it is an old library used by old applications that need to be replaced

Comment: @DanielA.White Thanks for the tip, I did not think about Reflector cause my licence just expired. Using another tool I can see that this method is just returning a Session parameter... So I can get this easily :)
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Using a decompiler tool, I saw that the method just returns a Session variable, so I can bypass it.